# Difference between "on display" and "in a display"?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

When a kid asks me where I placed his toy and I answer, "I put it on display near the window", would it be better if I say "It's in a display near the window?

Does it depend on contexts? For example, can I say "I saw the wedding gown on display at a shop"?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it depends on context. If something is *on display* it is placed where people can look at it, like your example of the wedding gown or a painting in a gallery.

If something is *in a display* it forms part of an arrangement of items, for example in a shop window or in a museum cabinet.

Answer (score 1):

The difference are small and the overlaps significant.

Among the many uses of *on* is

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/on)
>
> on: preposition (EXISTING)
>
> used to show that a condition or process exists or is being experienced:
> *The musicians are on strike.
>
> Are winter coats on sale?*

Therefore, the toy is on display when its condition is that of being displayed (in a window, on a hand, on a pedestal, in a museum and so forth)

If the toy is in a display, it is part of a collection of displayed objects.

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/display)
>
> display noun (ARRANGEMENT)
>
> a collection of objects or pictures arranged for people to look at, or a performance or show for people to watch:
> *There's an Egyptian art collection on display (= being shown) at the museum at the moment.*

The wedding gown may have been in a display (of several gowns) or it may have been on display as a single item. If it were displayed alone with special lighting or surroundings it could even be described as on display in an illuminated display.